# Google Analytics + EasyTracker (Android) track same activity when switching fast

Tags: android, google-analytics

I noticed that when I switch very fast between activities, GoogleAnalytics sends all GET requests (activity tracking) with the same name (watched in log).

I attached the source of EasyTracker and went with the debugger to the very last point in EasyTracker's code before calling the GoogleAnalytics library. There the name of the activities are correct. After that everything is a black box (there's no source for GoogleAnalytics) and then I see GET with the same name in log.

The GET request are almost identical. The only difference is the paramter utmqt.

What is it? Is it a bug of GoogleAnalytics? Has somebody else experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with the dispatch period?
You can change the number of seconds between which analytics will send fresh data?
I think by default it is 60 seconds
This [post](http://www.xatik.com/2012/03/27/how-to-use-google-analytics-in-android-applications/) explains how to do that, by adding a time parameter

TIME
(change the value TIME with the number of seconds)

If it is too short, be careful though that it doesn't overwhelm the connection of your users

Answer (score 0):

From the implementation of this Java library for GA, it looks like "utmqt" is the time difference between when the GA request is made and when the request actually gets dispatched to the network:
https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalyticstracker/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/dmurph/tracking/dispatch/AnalyticsDispatcher.java?r=65

Update: also see https://github.com/AttackPattern/CSharpAnalytics/blob/b227da375341876ec77deb8e49c4c4c2ef0c1cef/Source/CSharpAnalytics/Protocols/Urchin/UrchinParameterDefinitions.cs